# Write program using array instead of data table in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have code  that displays information about degrees in a datagridview. This program works but I just found out I need to display this information using arrays. Once I figured out how to display it in a data table it was really easy but I need to do it the other way. Some advice please!

```
Dim array As New DataTable
Dim array2 As New DataTable
Dim array3 As New DataTable


Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click

    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnDegrees_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDegrees.Click

    array.Clear()
    Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("1981")
    column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("2006")
    column3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    array.Clear()
    array.Columns.Add(column1)
    array.Columns.Add(column2)
    array.Columns.Add(column3)

    array.Rows.Add("Business", "200,521", "318,042")
    array.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "15,121", "47,480")
    array.Rows.Add("Education", "108,074", "107,238")
    array.Rows.Add("Engineering", "63,642", "67,045")
    array.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "100,513", "161,485")

    Me.dgvStudies.DataSource = array


End Sub

Private Sub btnChanges_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChanges.Click

    array2.Clear()
    Dim column4 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column5 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Change (1981-2006)")
    column5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")


    array2.Columns.Add(column4)
    array2.Columns.Add(column5)

    ''Display array two containing percentage changes''
    array2.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "214.0%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "60.7%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Business", "58.6%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Engineering", "5.3%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Education", "-0.8%")

    dgvStudies.DataSource = array2

End Sub

Private Sub btnHistogram_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHistogram.Click

    array3.Clear()

    Dim column6 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column6.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column7 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("")
    column7.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column8 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Degrees in 2006")
    column8.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    array3.Clear()
    array3.Columns.Add(column6)
    array3.Columns.Add(column7)
    array3.Columns.Add(column8)

    array3.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "*****", "47,480")
    array3.Rows.Add("Engineering", "*******", "67,045")
    array3.Rows.Add("Education", "***********", "107,238")
    array3.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "****************", "161,485")
    array3.Rows.Add("Business", "********************************", "67,045")

    dgvStudies.DataSource = array3

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A datatable is a kind of multi-dimensional array, and is the usual backing store for a grid. Can I ask why you would want to use a (multi-dimensional) array for this?

Comment: it is for an assignment. So your saying that a datatable is still an array? So i can keep what I already did?

Comment: @SadieStokes A `DataTable` is **not** an `Array`.

Comment: @Magnus thanks! still new to this whole thing!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array instead of a `DataTable` you also need to create an object that corresponds to you DataTable structure. This is an example of your "Degrees implementation" using arrays and a `Degrees` object.

```
Sub Main
    dim arr = new Degrees() { new Degrees("Business", "200,521", "318,042"),  new Degrees("Computer and info. science", "15,121", "47,480")}
    Me.dgvStudies.DataSource = arr
End Sub

public class Degrees
    public property FieldofStudy As string
    public property Year1986 As string
    public property Year2006 As string

    public sub new(byval fieldofStudy As string, byval year1986 As string, byval year2006 As string)
      Me.FieldofStudy = fieldofStudy
      Me.Year1986 = year1986
      Me.Year2006 = year2006
    end sub
end class
```

Comment: When I click the button to display the degrees though it doesn't give me the result I am looking for. Do I have to do column and row info like I did for the other buttons?

Comment: No, but perhaps you need to set up the grid to use the new column names (from the Degrees class). And what do you mean by "doesn't give me the result I am looking for" Whats wrong?